# How to access React Redux value only once?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just want to get a value once from the redux store, and use it once inside of a useEffect function.

However useSelector is required to be on the root level of a component, so it is run every render. This means if the value in my redux store is updated, all the child components get updated too.

I don't want that to happen. (For some reason, the redux update is interrupting some of my animations). I only want it to access useSelector once when the component is mounted.

How can I accomplish this?

Current, unwanted behavior:

```
const Test = () => {
    const select = useSelector(state=> state); // updates every dispatch
    
    useEffect(()=> {
       console.log(select.value);
       }, []);
...
}
```

Wanted behavior, if react would let me...

```
const Test = () => {
    useEffect(()=> {
       const select = useSelector(state=> state); // only accessed once, doesn't update children on later dispatches
       console.log(select.value);
       }, []);
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just grab the store and get the state using that. The store will not change, as long as you're not changing the store passed to the React Redux `<Provider>`.

```
const Test = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  console.log('Test rendered')

  useEffect(() => {
    const value = store.getState().value;
    console.log('useEffect value: ', value)
  }, [store]);

  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [equality check](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) function of useSelector:

```js
const select = useSelector(state => state, () => true);
```

By returning always true, you prevent updates to the data selected on mount in that component and thus the re-renders.

Comment: Boy I can always depend on SO in a pinch before I start writing ugly code xD. Thank you for this insight!

Answer (score 1):

The [equality-check method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71198180/977819) does avoid renders, but the subscription is still active and some (probably insignificant) code still runs.

If that matters, the following avoids the subscription entirely.

```
const store = useStore();
const [myState] = React.useState(() => store.getState().myState);
```